# require.js loop in marionette app

Tags: javascript, requirejs, marionette

I'm starting a marionette app and I try to structure it. So now I have:

```
define(["marionette", "handlebars", "routes"], function(Marionette, Handlebars, Route){
    var App = new Marionette.Application();
    ...
    App.addRegions({
        header: "#header_region",
        ...
    });

    App.addInitializer(function(options){
        ...
        new Route();
        Backbone.history.start();
    });

    return App;
});
```

and my routes looks like:

```
define(["marionette", "app", "header/view"], function(Marionette, App, headerView){
    var Route = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        routes : {
            '' : 'home'
        },
        home: function(){
            var header_view = new headerView();
            App.header.show(header_view);
            ...
        }
    });
    return Route;
});
```

Obviously I have a loop in dependencies here with App.header.show(header_view). What is the common way to solve it? How do you structure your Marionette app?

Comment: the loop in dependencies is not obvious to me can you explain that a bit more please.

Answer (score 1):

This was a great example that helped to get me going when building my first Marionette App: https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Marionette-Require-Boilerplate/tree/master/public/js/app

The way you currently have your route file set up is the backbone way of doing it. You should create a Marionette Controller that will respond to the App routes.

Also, you'll see that this person creates init files to specify all of the start up logic (specifying global static variables and instantiating the controller and router to be used).

Hope this helps!